# Selenium, get the href if this link in Ruby

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to testing and Selenium,

I am trying to assert two texts, I have already got the first one by:

```
driver.current_url
```

but I stuck to get the text of this href as the second text:

HTML code:

```
<div class="back">
  <a href="/applicant_submissions">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
    BACK
  </a>    
</div>
```

Ruby code:

```
element = driver.find_elements(:class,'view-link')[0].click
puts element
puts driver.current_url

div = driver.find_element(:class,'back')   
url = driver.findElement(By.linkText("BACK"))
puts url.href
```

At the end, I want to compare driver.current_url with url.href, but I could not get the href of this back button link.

Thanks.

Comment: Show how you tried?

Comment: I updated my code to show what I tried ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use CSS selector for finding "BACK" link: `.back>a`.

Code: `url = driver.find_element(:css, ".back>a").attribute("href")`.

Comment: stack backtrace:: Unable to locate element: .\.back\>a (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

Comment: @Majid, sorry I made mistake. I have updated my answer.

Comment: puts show only :   #<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x00000000036c0dd8>

Comment: @Majid, yes, because we found the only element. After that use should get "href" attribute of a tag. Updated answer...